# How to set the line style for each kdeplot in a jointgrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, jointplot

I am using seaborn to create a kdeplot with marginal distribution as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49658133/1232833). I adapted the code a little to give me this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
setosa = iris.loc[iris.species == "setosa"]
virginica = iris.loc[iris.species == "virginica"]

g = sns.JointGrid(x="sepal_width", y="petal_length", data=iris)
sns.kdeplot(setosa.sepal_width, setosa.sepal_length, cmap="Reds",
        shade=False, shade_lowest=False, ax=g.ax_joint)
sns.kdeplot(virginica.sepal_width, virginica.sepal_length, cmap="Blues",
        shade=False, shade_lowest=False, ax=g.ax_joint)
sns.distplot(setosa.sepal_width, kde=True, hist=False, color="r", ax=g.ax_marg_x)
sns.distplot(virginica.sepal_width, kde=True, hist=False, color="b", ax=g.ax_marg_x)
sns.distplot(setosa.sepal_length, kde=True, hist=False, color="r", ax=g.ax_marg_y, vertical=True)
sns.distplot(virginica.sepal_length, kde=True, hist=False, color="b", ax=g.ax_marg_y, vertical=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is impossible to print in black and white. **How can I get seaborn to print the kdeplot and distplot lines in a specifically styled (dotted / dashed / ...) way to make them distinguishable when printed in black and white?**

The [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44261803/change-line-style-in-seaborn-facet-grid) deal with other types of plots which appear to support this, but this does not seem to be supported by [kdeplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html) and [distplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html).

Comment: The answer you got provided you with a [mcve]. Yet instead of using this, you fall back to use some code noone can run.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Good point. Edited it to include a better example.

Comment: How did you get both kdeplots to show up on the same plot? I have tried very similar code but only one shows up at a time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Marginals

To show the lines of a kde plot with a different linestyle you can use the `linestyle` argument, which is passed on to matplotlib's corresponding plot function.

```
sns.kdeplot(setosa.sepal_width, color="r", ax=g.ax_marg_x, linestyle="--")
```

To provide this argument to the kde plot which is produced via `distplot` you may use the `kde_kws` argument.

```
sns.distplot(..., kde_kws={"linestyle":"--"})
```

However, there does not seem to be any reason to use a distplot here.

#### Joint KDE

For the 2D case, the linestyle argument has no effect. A 2D kdeplot is a `contour` plot. Hence you need to use the `contour`'s `linestyles` (note the `s`) argument.

```
sns.kdeplot(, linestyles="--")
```

#### Complete code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
setosa = iris.loc[iris.species == "setosa"]
virginica = iris.loc[iris.species == "virginica"]

g = sns.JointGrid(x="sepal_width", y="petal_length", data=iris)

sns.kdeplot(setosa.sepal_width, setosa.sepal_length, cmap="Reds",
            shade=False, shade_lowest=False, ax=g.ax_joint, linestyles="--")
sns.kdeplot(virginica.sepal_width, virginica.sepal_length, cmap="Blues",
            shade=False, shade_lowest=False, ax=g.ax_joint, linestyles=":")

sns.kdeplot(setosa.sepal_width, color="r", legend=False,  
            ax=g.ax_marg_x, linestyle="--")
sns.kdeplot(virginica.sepal_width, color="b", legend=False, 
            ax=g.ax_marg_x, linestyle=":")
sns.kdeplot(setosa.sepal_length, color="r", legend=False, 
            ax=g.ax_marg_y, vertical=True, linestyle="--")
sns.kdeplot(virginica.sepal_length, color="b", legend=False, 
            ax=g.ax_marg_y, vertical=True, linestyle=":")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Any keywords that `sns.kdeplot` does not recognise are passed to `plt.contour()` or `plt.contourf()`. In your case it is `contourf`, so you can pass the keyword `linestyles` (note the plural). `sns.distplot` has a keyword that is called `kde_kws`, which accepts a dictionary of keywords that are passed to `plt.plot`. In this case you can use `ls` or `linestyle` (note the singular). Below is a complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
setosa = iris.loc[iris.species == "setosa"]
virginica = iris.loc[iris.species == "virginica"]

g = sns.JointGrid(x="sepal_width", y="petal_length", data=iris)
sns.kdeplot(
    setosa.sepal_width, setosa.sepal_length, cmap="Greys",
    shade=False, shade_lowest=False, ax=g.ax_joint,
    linestyles='--'
)
sns.kdeplot(
    virginica.sepal_width, virginica.sepal_length, cmap="Greys",
    shade=False, shade_lowest=False, ax=g.ax_joint,
    linestyles=':'
)
sns.distplot(
    setosa.sepal_width, kde=True, hist=False, color="k",
    kde_kws=dict(ls ='--'), ax=g.ax_marg_x
)
sns.distplot(
    virginica.sepal_width, kde=True, hist=False, color="k",
    kde_kws=dict(ls=':'), ax=g.ax_marg_x
)
sns.distplot(
    setosa.sepal_length, kde=True, hist=False, color="k",
    kde_kws=dict(ls ='--'), ax=g.ax_marg_y, vertical=True
)
sns.distplot(
    virginica.sepal_length, kde=True, hist=False, color="k",
    kde_kws=dict(ls=':'), ax=g.ax_marg_y, vertical=True
)
plt.show()
```

And the result looks like this:

[image: result of the above code]